# Roots of Monic Irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x])/\pi(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $K=(\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x])/\pi(x)$ where $\pi\in\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a monic irreducible. Let $\Theta\in K$ denote the class of $x$. Show that each of $\Theta, \Theta^p, \Theta^{p^2}, \ldots, \Theta^{p^k}$ are roots of $\pi$ in $K$. Does $\pi$ factor in $K[x]$ as a product of the terms $(x-\Theta^{p^k})$ with no other factors? Moreover, how can we characterize the smallest $m>0$ such that $\Theta^{p^m}=\Theta$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the basic theorems and terminology from Galois theory?

Answer (score 1):

You can show (if you haven't seen this already) that
$$
\mathbb{Z}\lbrack x \rbrack/p\mathbb{Z}\lbrack x \rbrack \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\lbrack x \rbrack,
$$
and it's easier to work in the space on the right.

So I'll assume that you're considering $\theta = x + (\pi(x))$ in $K = \mathbb{F}_p\lbrack x\rbrack/(\pi(x))$ for a monic irreducible $\pi(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p\lbrack x \rbrack$. (Here $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ just denotes the field with $p$ elements.) Note $K$ is a field since $(\pi(x))$ is maximal in $\mathbb{F}_p\lbrack x \rbrack$, and it contains $\mathbb{F}_p$ as a subfield.

If $\pi(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k x^k$, then let $\bar\pi(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\bar{a}_k X^k \in K\lbrack X\rbrack$ where $\bar{a}_k = a_k + (\pi(x))$ is the image of $a_k$ in $K$. Then notice
\begin{align*}
\bar\pi(\theta) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \bar{a}_k (x+(\pi(x)))^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + (\pi(x))) (x+(\pi(x)))^k \\
&= \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k\right) + (\pi(x)) \\
&= \pi(x) + (\pi(x)) = 0 + (\pi(x)) = \bar{0}
\end{align*}
where (for clarity) I'm denoting $\bar{0}$ for the zero element in $K$.

This shows that $\theta$ is, in fact, a root of $\bar\pi(X)$, which is to say (under the usual identification of elements of $\mathbb{F}_p\lbrack x\rbrack$ and their images in $K\lbrack X \rbrack$) that $\pi(\theta) = 0$.

So now you need to show that $\pi(\theta^{p^k}) = 0$ (*i.e.*, that $\bar\pi(\theta^{p^k}) = \bar0$) for $k \geq 1$. I'll leave the details to you, but you can show that
$$
\sigma: \alpha \mapsto \alpha^p
$$
defines a field automorphism of $K$, and then use this to conclude that
$$
\pi(\theta^{p^k}) = \pi(\sigma^k(\theta)) = \sigma^k(\pi(\theta)) = 0
$$
for all $k \geq 0$.

(In fact, you can show that the automorphism group $G = \text{Aut}(K/\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cyclic and generated by $\sigma$.)

---

The above argument shows that some of the roots of $\pi(x)$ are of the form $\theta^{p^k}$ but not necessarily all of them. To show that they are in fact all of that form, it's enough to show that $\theta^{p^k} \neq \theta$ for $k < n$. (Why?) Note $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and hence of the form $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ for some $r \geq 1$. Then you'll be able to show that $\theta^{p^k} \neq \theta$ for $k < n$ is true after arguing that $r = n = \deg(\pi)$.